# Generate presignedURL with Lambda when upload new object to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

i searched everywhere but i cannot find a script which allows lambda to generate a presigned url when i upload a new object to an s3 bucket. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll find an already-made solution online, but the following workflow should work :

- Catch the S3 upload event using [S3 notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html) and trigger a Lambda.
- Make the Lambda retrieve the name of the objects and creates a pre-signed URL.
- Upload this URL to a DynamoDB table (or anything else which fits your use-case. SSM Parameter Store for example).

Make sure your Lambda has all the correct rights, and pay attention to the fact S3 pre-signed URL generated with SDK have a expiration date of [7 days max](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html).

Comment: Thanks! your solution is just what i had in mind except storing the url in a db. I'm stuck in the code to let lambda to retrieve the name of the uploaded object

Comment: AWS has some good examples in its [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) in how to do that.